# django and postgres - support hebrew

Tags: django, postgresql, text, utf-8, hebrew

I have been trying to make this work for a while.. driving me crazy.

When I try to send POST request to my django app with **Hebrew** text, it stores the Hebrew text as `???????`.

I thought it might be a problem in my **postgres database**, but its Encoding is **UTF-8**, and also, when I access the table entries manually, I can change the text to Hebrew and its fine.

What am I doing wrong? How can send POST requests with Hebrew text and store it successfully in the DB??

**UPDATE: SOLVED**

Apparently, my mistake was so simple and annoying...

In the android app, when you set the params, I did this:

```
se = new StringEntity(obj.toString());
```

When I changed my code and added the `UTF_8`, it solved the issue:

```
se = new StringEntity(obj.toString(), HTTP.UTF_8);
```

Just needed to add the `UTF_8` Encoding..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [decoding and encoding Hebrew string in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29850912/decoding-and-encoding-hebrew-string-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using python 2 or python 3?  In python 2 literal strings are not literals.  You have to explicitly cast them as unicode like this:

```
u'Stuff'
```

See here for more details [Unicode literals that work in python 3 and 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625782/unicode-literals-that-work-in-python-3-and-2)

You can import that one feature from python 3 using this too

http://python-future.org/unicode_literals.html

This also seems relevant to your problem:

[decoding and encoding Hebrew string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29850912/decoding-and-encoding-hebrew-string-in-python)

Comment: I am using python 3.4

Comment: I would check by running a local server with django (./manage.py runserver) and then sending some example posts from a browser.  You can then print out what your Django view is receiving immediately as you enter your django end-point and see if the problem is there or if something is going wrong when you put that in your database

Comment: thanks! I think that helped.. now what is happening is: if I POST from my android app to django - it stores the hebrew string as ????, BUT - I tried to post from chrome POSTMAN - and it works! it stores the String in hebrew. the weird thing is I also check the data right before I send it from the app - and its in hebrew.. where is the problem??

Comment: I would thing then then problem is that your android app is failing to encode the utf-8 Hebrew (it's probably just trying to use normal ascii) so its a problem with the app and not your Django project/your postgres DB

Comment: Yes you are right:)  see my updated question with the solution

Comment: Nice one.  Remember to close off the question too.

Comment: close it..? when I click "close" which option should I go with? there is no "the question has been answered" option.

Comment: You normally select an answer but I dont know if this is relevant now