# How can i print a Hebrew phrase in python 3 terminal?

Tags: python, unicode, printing, hebrew

Do someone know why my python 3 terminal does not show unicode properly ?

```
text= "בראשית ברא אלהים את השמים ואת הארץ".encode("UTF-8")
print (text)
```

but the output is :

```
b'\xd7\x91\xd7\xa8\xd7\x90\xd7\xa9\xd7\x99\xd7\xaa \xd7\x91\xd7\xa8\xd7\x90 \xd7\x90\xd7\x9c\xd7\x94\xd7\x99\xd7\x9d \xd7\x90\xd7\xaa \xd7\x94\xd7\xa9\xd7\x9e\xd7\x99\xd7\x9d \xd7\x95\xd7\x90\xd7\xaa \xd7\x94\xd7\x90\xd7\xa8\xd7\xa5'
```

How can to print it properly ?

or if i dont encode it :

```
text= "בראשית ברא אלהים את השמים ואת הארץ"
print (text)
```

this error comes out:

```
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
```

UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-5: character maps to

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29850912/decoding-and-encoding-hebrew-string-in-python)? I think that can help you.

Comment: This is OS-specifc, but for Windows you can install Hebrew language support and then switch to a Hebrew-supporting font in the CMD window.  I've done this with Chinese and it works great. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63893448/235698).

Answer (score 0):

You can either avoid encoding, or encode and then decode.

```
In [1]: text= "בראשית ברא אלהים את השמים ואת הארץ"

In [2]: print(text)
בראשית ברא אלהים את השמים ואת הארץ

In [3]: encoded = text.encode('utf8')

In [4]: decoded = encoded.decode('utf8')

In [5]: print(decoded)
בראשית ברא אלהים את השמים ואת הארץ
```

Answer (score 0):

`text` is a `bytes` value. `print` takes `str` values; `str(b'foo')` is not `'foo'`, but `"b'foo'"`.

Don't encode `text` in the first place. It's already a suitable value to use as an argument for `print`. Any encoding needed for your terminal is done by the file-like object `print` writes to.

```
text = "בראשית ברא אלהים את השמים ואת הארץ"
print(text)
```